# saltstack: Targeting minions based on grains[id] of other minions

Tags: salt-stack

during a deployment: two minions are brought up, I want to target one minion if the other minion has a specific grain['id'], how would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the `-G` option, you can target minions by grains data

See https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/targeting/

Not sure what do you mean by `I want to target one minion if the other minion has a specific grain['id'], how would I do that`.
But if you want to do some complex targeting, you can try salt orchestration.

Comment: I mean "I want to target one minion with a particular state file based on the other minion's grains for example: i want a particular state file to run on one minion when the other minion's grain[kernel]==windows.

Comment: You can achieve that by adding a separate grain or pillar to the target, and then add the state to highstate based on grain/pillar

Comment: But grains/pillar data is not accessible by other minions. One way to read pillar/grains data of other minions is through mine function. What you can do is create a mine function `get_os`